# JQuery tabs is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting the follow error on my site. Finding difficult to figure out the error.

Site link is

```
https://giftfind.ca/productdesc.php?skuid=B00NIYJKL0&category=All&keywords=gopro%20hero4#.W6RLgmgzZPb


Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (productdesc.php?skuid=B00NIYJKL0&category=All&keywords=gopro hero4:582)
at fire (jquery-1.js:974)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.js:1082)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.js:406)
at HTMLDocument.DOMContentLoaded (jquery-1.js:83)
```

Comment: You're loading **many** different copies of jQuery. Don't do that. Load one copy of jQuery then one copy of each plugin or add-on you need

Comment: What are the list of jquery am I loading?

Comment: It's your source code man, you tell me. I went to your page, selected _"View page source"_ and did a `Ctrl+f` for "jquery"

Comment: yes they are different libraries right?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed Just like @Phil said you have more than 1 JQuery library included in your page such as `jquery-1` and `jquery-1.4`... I guess you accidentally multiple include the js file